# What is happening when a company wants to trade on a new stock exchange

Tags: stock-markets, germany, bulgaria

I invested a year ago 5000 € in a company, listed on the Bulgarian (BG) stock exchange, because I really believed in their home automation products. Today it is doing well and after a capital increase, the company wants to be listed on a new stock exchange, Frankfurt (FRA). Mainly because its biggest market is in Germany.

They are in the process to fill an admission to trading on a regulated market.

I'm not sure I understand exactly what's going to happen and what the impacts are going to be.
I understand that it is also interesting for the company because few brokers are active on the BG stock exchange and being listed on FRA would make it possible to be much more liquid, to reach a more varied investor audience. I also understand that the securities will be listed in EUR instead of LV (bulgarian currency)

I don't understand what the impact will be, here is what I think: there is no issuance of new securities, only the securities will be traded on another stock exchange.
But ultimately there is no issuance of new titles. I could possibly even ask my broker who takes care of FRA's place to take over my securities from my old broker (who only does BG)

Is it correct ? Thank you in advance for your advice !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be a double listing. Many companies have their shares listed in more than one stock exchange and all continue to be traded simultaneously. You don't need to do anything unless the company is applying to BG stock exchange to withdraw its listing in BG.

Comment: It will be a double listing. But how will the stock will be traded on the new stock exchange ?

Comment: Some of the shareholders can make some of their existing shares exclusively available for trading in Frankfurt Stock Exchange (FSE) to create supply after the company's application to list in FSE is accepted. Those shares might need to be re-registered in Germany or depositary receipts that represent the company's shares might be created. [This article](https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/knowledge/trading-investing/dual-listing/) has some details about how multiple listings are usually done.

Comment: @user1707414 people will sign up for brokers and trade stocks on the exchange via their brokers. Same as any other exchange